# Angular 2 ngIf only showing for a split second

Tags: html, angular

I'm having a weird problem with an Angular 2 ngIf statement only showing on the page for a split second and then disappearing. It's working because I see it but it doesn't want to stay on the page. Guessing it's some sort of weird a-sync thing. Here's the code:

```
<div class="holder">
<h2 *ngIf="!this.userHomeService.cards">
    You haven't created any cards.
</h2>
<div class="card-div" 
*ngFor="let c of this.userHomeService.cards">
    <h3 (click)="onSelect(c)">{{c.title}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: the `ngIf` isn't stopping the next statement, the `ngFor`, from being displayed.  do you see errors in the console coming from the `ngFor` statement about `this.userHomeService.cards` being `undefined`?

Comment: it doesn't seem like either are getting displayed. If I add a card then that appears, otherwise there's nothing. I don't get any console errors

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your controller, but I can guess what it contains.

1. `this.userHomeService.cards` is undefined or null. So `!this.userHomeService.cards` is true, and "You haven't created any cards." is displayed on the page. The ngFor doesn't display anything, since there is nothing to iterate on.
2. A response to some asynchronous request, probably a HTTP request, comes back, and it's an empty array. So the ngFor still doesn't display anything, since the array is empty, but `!this.userHomeService.cards` becomes false, and the message disappears from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `*ngIf="this.userHomeService.cards"` for the second `div` to avoid any errors for undefined value.

```
<div *ngIf="this.userHomeService.cards">
  <div class="card-div" *ngFor="let c of this.userHomeService.cards">
    <h3 (click)="onSelect(c)">{{c.title}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

To avoid displaying `You haven't created any cards.` message initially on the page (wile fetching data) you have to have some kind of flag indicating that you data is still loading from server. For example:

```
<h2 *ngIf="this.finished && !this.userHomeService.cards">
    You haven't created any cards.
</h2>
```

And add `finished` variable to your controller and set it to true when your http request is finished.

So this message will be shown only when you data fetching is finished.

(this is one of possible solutions of your problem, the simplest one I suppose)

Comment: Is it really possible to use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` in the same element? I don't think so.

Comment: @Claies, well, I just tested it now **on the same element** and how I was suspecting it throws an error: `Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *`.

Comment: @developer033 in this case just use nested elements (updated answer)

Comment: Of course dude :) I hope you don't get me wrong, it was just a mini correction :)